# How do I pin my tracing-core version to 0.1.26?

Tags: substrate-node-template, cargo

In the substrate-node-template, I can't see the local node identity whenever I start the node with `./target/release/node-template --dev`: e.g.

[image]

Apparently to fix this I need to pin my tracing-core version to 0.1.26, but I do not know how I can do this. I've tried running `cargo update -p tracing-core --precise 0.1.26` but I get this error:
`error: failed to select a version for the requirement`tracing-core = "^0.1.27"`candidate versions found which didn't match: 0.1.26`

I'm also not sure how to modify the Cargo.toml files in `substrate-node-template` to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is an issue for this:

- https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11855

I was able to replicate this issue on:

- https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/releases/tag/polkadot-v0.9.26

Logs are working for me fine on:

- https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/releases/tag/polkadot-v0.9.28

Try using `polkadot-v0.9.28` tag of the node-template.